# HTK: HCompV ReadString: String too long

Tags: linux, speech-recognition, raspbian, raspberry-pi2, htk

Hi i am new at HTK and have followed "A Tutorial Example of Using HTK" in The HTK Book from http://htk.eng.cam.ac.uk/

I have gotten to the point where i have to use "HCompV" (3.2.1 Step 6 - Creating Flat Start Monophones )

i have "cd" to my working dir and my command goes as

```
HCompV -C wav_config_HCompV -f 0.01 -m -S train.silmodel.scp -M hmm0 proto.silmodel
```

(Dont mind the weird names ive made a few attempts to get to here and renamed new file versions with new names to keep the old)

My "wav_config_HCompV" Contains

```
TARGETKIND = MFCC_0_D_A
TARGETRATE = 100000.0
SAVECOMPRESSED = T
SAVEWITHCRC = T
WINDOWSIZE = 250000.0
USEHAMMING = T
PREEMCOEF = 0.97
NUMCHANS = 26
CEPLIFTER = 22
NUMCEPS = 12
```

My "train.silmodel.scp" contains

```
"/home/pi/HTK/htk.eng.cam.ac.uk/HTK Book/train/wav-2/S0001.wav"
"/home/pi/HTK/htk.eng.cam.ac.uk/HTK Book/train/wav-2/S0002.wav"
"/home/pi/HTK/htk.eng.cam.ac.uk/HTK Book/train/wav-2/S0003.wav"
"/home/pi/HTK/htk.eng.cam.ac.uk/HTK Book/train/wav-2/S0004.wav"
"/home/pi/HTK/htk.eng.cam.ac.uk/HTK Book/train/wav-2/S0005.wav"
"/home/pi/HTK/htk.eng.cam.ac.uk/HTK Book/train/wav-2/S0006.wav"
"/home/pi/HTK/htk.eng.cam.ac.uk/HTK Book/train/wav-2/S0007.wav"
etc...
```

and my "proto.silmodel" contains

```
~o <VecSize> 39 <MFCC_0_D_A>
~h "proto
<BeginHMM>
<NumStates> 5
<State> 2
<Mean> 39
0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
<Variance> 39
1.0 1.0 1.0 ...
<State> 3
<Mean> 39
0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
<Variance> 39
1.0 1.0 1.0 ...
<State> 4
<Mean> 39
0.0 0.0 0.0 ...
<Variance> 39
1.0 1.0 1.0 ...
<TransP> 5
0.0 1.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 
0.0 0.6 0.4 0.0 0.0 
0.0 0.0 0.6 0.4 0.0 
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.7 0.3 
0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 0.0 
<EndHMM>
```

When i run the command i get the error

```
ERROR [+5013]  ReadString: String too long
FATAL ERROR - Terminating program HCompV
```

Which i find rather odd. Since on pages like 
[understanding htk error messages](http://www.ling.ohio-state.edu/~bromberg/htk_problems.html)

i end up finding not in "HCompV" error message but "HLed" error saying

```
ERROR [+5013] ReadString: String too long
FATAL ERROR - Terminating program HLEd
```

and the solution should be

```
Make changes to the pronunciation dictionary:
Replace all multiple spaces with single space;
Replace all tabs with single space;
Put a '\' before every double quote ("); %"
Put a '\' before any dictionary entry beginning with single quote (')
```

i cant see how this error code in any way has anything to do with HCompV and no other place on the net have i found anything relating to my weird error.
Is there any out there who has a clue ?

i dont seem to have any dictionary in this comman so it doest add up.

Ty for reading so for and best regards,
Darkyere

Comment: The file "train.silmodel.scp" does not look correct. Each line should have the path to a .wav file followed by the path to the corresponding .mfc file. Your lines show a wav path preceded by an htk directory. The space in "HTK Book" likely is causing a parse problem.

Answer (score 0):

This error is caused by a missing new line in the end of some of the input files. Make sure that each input file ends with a newline. You can use any good text editor for that.

Comment: There was a need of NewLine in 2 of the files but it still pulls out the same error. Any clue why that might be ?

Comment: You can share your files in archive if you need more detailed help

Answer (score 0):

Input files to `HCompV` have to be in mfc format, not wav. Convert all wavs to mfc via `HCopy` and change `train.silmodel.scp` file indicating paths of mfc files.